# v-treeview make items checked during initial load

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using v-treeview to make nested selection. How can I make some items are selected during initial loading? How can we access the checkbox properties of items in a treeview? After selections, the v-model array gives the aray of selected items, I have tried updating this array during loading but did not work.

Please see below code, on Save click, tree1 array gets updated with selected item Ids. I have tried, adding some Id's to this array to make simulate selected items but did nit help.

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
   
    isLoading: false,
    accounts: [],
    isLoading1: false,
    tree1: ['174'],
    mspName: '',
    selectedList: [{id: '174', selected: true},{id: '191', selected: true}]
    
  }),

  computed: {
    
    items2() {
      
      */
      console.log('computed: items 2 called');
      
      var children = this.accounts.filter(function(cur){
        if(cur.parent =='0') {
          return [{id: cur.id,name: cur.msp_name}];
        }

      });
      
      console.log(children);
      console.log('length of children: '+children.length)
      const having_parent = this.accounts.filter(function(cur){
        if(cur.parent !=='0') {
          var parent_index = children.findIndex(element => element.id ===cur.parent);
          console.log('found parent: '+parent_index);
          if(children[parent_index]['children'] == undefined) {
            children[parent_index]['children']=[];
          }
          
          children[parent_index]['children'].push(cur);
        }
      });
      
      return([{id: 1,name: this.mspName, children}]);
      
    },
    selections1() {
      const selections1 = [];

      for (const leaf of this.tree1) {
        const account = this.accounts.find(account => account.id === leaf);

        if (!account) continue;

        selections1.push(account);
      }

      return selections1;
    },
    shouldShowTree1() {
      return this.accounts.length > 0 && !this.isLoading1;
    },
    
  },

  methods: {
    
    fetchAccounts() {
      console.log('fecth accounts called...')
      if (this.accounts.length) return;

      return fetch("http://192.168.2.74:4000/msp", { method: "POST" })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.accounts = data[0].msp_accounts;
          this.mspName = data[0].msp_name;
          console.log("msp accounts fetched");
          console.log(this.accounts);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
    
    
    save() {
      console.log('save clicked');
      console.log(this.tree1);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchAccounts();
   
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-toolbar card color="grey lighten-3">
      <v-icon>home</v-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title></v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-layout>
      <v-flex>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-treeview
            v-model="tree1"          
            :items="items2"
            activatable
            active-class="grey lighten-4 indigo--text"
            selected-color="indigo"
            open-on-click
            selectable
            expand-icon="mdi-chevron-down"
            on-icon="mdi-bookmark"
            off-icon="mdi-bookmark-outline"
            indeterminate-icon="mdi-bookmark-minus"

          ></v-treeview>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-flex>

      <v-divider vertical></v-divider>

      <v-flex xs12 md6>
        <v-card-text>
          <div
            v-if="selections1.length === 0"
            key="title"
            class="title font-weight-light grey--text pa-3 text-xs-center"
          >Select your accounts</div>

          <v-scroll-x-transition group hide-on-leave>
            <v-chip v-for="(selection, i) in selections1" :key="i" color="grey" dark small>
              <v-icon left small>trash-can</v-icon>
              {{ selection.name }}
            </v-chip>
          </v-scroll-x-transition>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn flat @click="tree1 = []">Reset</v-btn>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn class="white--text" color="green darken-1" depressed @click="save">
        Save
        <v-icon right>mdi-content-save</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample to better explain the problem or what you have already tried. Also consider adding runnable example using jsfiddle.net, codepen.io, plnkr.co etc or use 'stack snippets' by using by clicking the [<>] toolbar button in the edit section. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Two things available in vuetify  tag

1. V-model
2. Item

Solution

1. Just Push all data in items respected to item and children style.
2. For Checking Data just during initial load just pass those items in v-model on the created hook.
3. Now, Check Output is shows checked box.

Hope it will Help.!